# Ordering specific data in a DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I am stuck right now with a specific data format which can't be ordered in an ordinary way.
 Example: ["Last Active" column ordered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i0iB.png)

I am trying with the html-attribute data-order

```
<td data-order="1447147318">8 months, 4 weeks</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td data-order="1460026800">Apr 07 2016 13:00:00 </td>
<td data-order="1460026800">Apr 07 2016 13:00:00</td>
```

but this ain't working. It still orders it alphabetically.
The "Last Active" data is calculated by subtracting a given timestamp by the current timestamp.
I have found some code to exclude empty data cells from sorting which is needed aswell.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "non-empty-string-asc": function (str1, str2) {
        if (str1 == "-")
            return 1;
        if (str2 == "-")
            return -1;
        return ((str1 < str2) ? -1 : ((str1 > str2) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "non-empty-string-desc": function (str1, str2) {
        if (str1 == "-")
            return 1;
        if (str2 == "-")
            return -1;
        return ((str1 < str2) ? 1 : ((str1 > str2) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});

_j(function () {
    _j('#customerTable').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            {"data": "ID"},
            {"data": "Type"},
            {"data": "Customer"},
            {"data": "Act", "defaultContent": ""},
            {"data": "KND", "defaultContent": ""},
            {"data": "Last Active", "defaultContent": "Not logged yet", "type": "non-empty-string"},
            {"data": "Total", "defaultContent": ""},
            {"data": "Today", "defaultContent": ""},
            {"data": "Min Trial", "defaultContent": "", "type": "non-empty-string"},
            {"data": "Max Trial", "defaultContent": "", "type": "date"}
        ],
        "pageLength": 20,
        "lengthMenu": [10, 15, 20, 50, 100]
    });

});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please send fiddle so i can check you entire code and rectify

Comment: here  you go: https://jsfiddle.net/mu8d5y4c/
It contains the main datasets and the script i use to exclude empty cells from sorting

Answer (score 0):

How are you comparing the strings?  When I put an alert in the sort to see the value of str1 and atr2, I was seeing the text values, e.g. "1 month, 2 weeks" and "1 week, 1 day".  Given you're doing a string comparison, it's not unexpected for it to return in alphanumerical order.

Comment: Yeah. That's my problem. Is there a simpler way of sorting this type of data? Or will i end up with my fear coding a sorting algorithm myself -ain't good at algorithms.

Comment: I'd have to see the underlining data and know more about how you want it sorted. When I do in one of my tables is format the date using moment.js (using datatables render function), but sort it using the timestamps (longs)

Comment: I got it working, that it sorts the data right. But sadly it costed me the exclusion of empty data cells.

The clue was to remove the data specification when i initialize the dataTable so it detects data automatically.
https://jsfiddle.net/mu8d5y4c/2/

Now it sorts the right way. But any idea how i could exclude these empty data-cells "-" from being sorted?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstandings,
"-" should not be displayed. 
Now i get the most recent active users and on the other end i get 100 users with "-" because those didn't log in once. Hence, there is no timestamp available.
But i still want the oldest activity to be displayed if a user was 9 Months not online this should be displayed if sorted.

This has already worked on my first JS FIddle: jsfiddle.net/mu8d5y4c. The one row with id=19 "Last Active" = "-" doesn't get displayed when sorted. Or if you sort "Min Trial" the "-" cells are always on the bottom. No matter ASC DESC sorted.